# Quantify Sweetness?

Tags: carbohydrates

My textbook gives many examples of sweetening agents. For Alitame it says its 2000 times sweeter than cane sugar. Aspartame is 100 times sweeter than sugar.
 
I am wondering how they quantify sweetness?

Comment: Dilute the compound until you can't tell it from pure water, then check the concentration.

Comment: But that measures the intensity not sweetness right? Maybe Aspartame isnt really all that sweet but the intensity is very high?

Comment: What's the distinction between the two?